# Populating a dropdown list from data table

Tags: php, html

I have a form which is used for editing user records. The form has a dropdown list which is populated with time in hours from the users mysql data record.

This works, but at the same time I want to be able to select a new time (Hours) from the static list.

This is what I have:

```
<select name="RoomFromTimeH" id="RoomFromTimeH" class="imaindatesel">
<option value="00" <?php if (!(strcmp(00, $HourRoomFromTime))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>00</option>
<option value="01" <?php if (!(strcmp(01, $HourRoomFromTime))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>01</option>
<option value="02" <?php if (!(strcmp(02, $HourRoomFromTime))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>02</option>
<option value="03" <?php if (!(strcmp(03, $HourRoomFromTime))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>03</option>
<option value="04" <?php if (!(strcmp(04, $HourRoomFromTime))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>04</option>
<option value="05" <?php if (!(strcmp(05, $HourRoomFromTime))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>05</option>
<option value="06" <?php if (!(strcmp(06, $HourRoomFromTime))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>06</option>
</select>
```

The $HourRoomFromTime is the variabe wich hold the hours from the data record. This is only part of the static list, it goes from 00 to 23.

How can this be done.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Why don't you put your `<option>` tags inside a for loop?

Comment: @pappfer How would that solve the issue? Many thats for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your are look for. Try for with [str_pad](http://php.net/str_pad) the for will genarete 00 to 24

```
<select name="RoomFromTimeH" id="RoomFromTimeH" class="imaindatesel">
<?php for($i=0; $i<24; $i++ ):  
      $time = str_pad($i, 2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
?>
<option value="<?=$time?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($time, $HourRoomFromTime))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?=$time?></option>
<?php endfor;?>

</select>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, fixed and working. A lot less code which is great.